# Libvirt Yubikey passthrough

Tags: ubuntu, libvirt, usb-device, yubikey

So I've been trying to get a yubikey passthrough to work for a few days now with no luck. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what's wrong with my setup?

**Setup:**
I'm using ubuntu 18.04 as both host and guest.
Libvirt for virtualisation

**Procedure:**
I'm passing through the usb using the following hostdev section:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <product id='0x1050'/>
    <vendor id='0x0407'/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
```

I boot the VM and verify that the usb was passed through properly with `lsusb`. (And it is)
Then I try `yubico-piv-tool -a status` to see if the key is working.

**Results:**
`yubico-piv-tool -a status` returns "Failed to read device".

**Observations:**
The yubikey functions on the host, `yubico-piv-tool -a status` prints as expected.
The yubikey still shows up on the host after the passthrough when I run `lsusb` on the host.
The yubikey does not function on the host while the passthrough is active.
I've tried to passthrough the yubikey on a laptop with a windows host on virtualbox and was successful with no extra settings.
I tried virtualbox on the linux host and was not successful, same results as with libvirt.

While the USB device is not passed through, `lsusb -t` shows that it's not assigned to any driver; when passed through, it's owned by the `usbfs` driver, and the libvirt-qemu user's `qemu-syst` process has the device open.

**My guess:**
There's missing parameters on the passthrough and the key isn't getting passed entirely (Something CCID/FIDO/OTP related?).
The virtualization software was not able to disconnect the device from the host.

Comment: Since my answer was a dead end, I deleted it, but integrated your findings from the comments there in the observations here.